# Java GC log footer mean

Tags: logging, garbage-collection, java

I already have an idea of ​​the lines after each garbage collection. Also I have an idea of ​​the garbage collector generations. That one thing I misunderstood:

```
56.897: [GC 56.897: [DefNew: 4919K->512K(4928K), 0.0117236 secs] 8670K->4850K(15872K), 0.0118473 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
66.191: [GC 66.191: [DefNew: 4928K->206K(4928K), 0.0094325 secs] 9266K->5046K(15872K), 0.0095556 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
...
Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 439K [0x24380000, 0x248d0000, 0x298d0000)
  eden space 4416K,   3% used [0x24380000, 0x243abe18, 0x247d0000)
  from space 512K,  51% used [0x247d0000, 0x24811ec0, 0x24850000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24850000, 0x24850000, 0x248d0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 4840K [0x298d0000, 0x2a380000, 0x34380000)
   the space 10944K,  44% used [0x298d0000, 0x29d8a1e8, 0x29d8a200, 0x2a380000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3677K [0x34380000, 0x34f80000, 0x38380000)
   the space 12288K,  29% used [0x34380000, 0x34717578, 0x34717600, 0x34f80000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38380000, 0x387c1d60, 0x387c1e00, 0x38d80000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38d80000, 0x39402928, 0x39402a00, 0x39980000)
```

Okay, let this footer represent GC heaps state at program's shutdown moment. Then I can understand the meaning of `total` and `used`.

Then goes `[0x298d0000, 0x2a380000, 0x34380000)` which opens square bracket and closes round. Probably that mean physical memory addresses, but why 3 for generation and 4 for space.

```
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 4840K [0x298d0000, 0x2a380000, 0x34380000)
   the space 10944K,  44% used [0x298d0000, 0x29d8a1e8, 0x29d8a200, 0x2a380000)
```

And what is the purpose of giving this information to the user? I would be happy to get link to documentation describing the output of the garbage collector.